# Error when deploying to QA using continuous deployment

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, release-management

[image]I have console app which I have to deploy in 3 different environments(QA, staging and production), I created a release build the kicked off the build, for the first time QA deployed successfully with no issues, and staging also followed through perfectly, however I realised that QA and staging are pointing to the same server(server1), I then changed the server name on staging environment from server1 to server2, the restarted the entire deployment from scratch(starting from QA).

I am now getting following error "##[error]Could not find files with glob [E:\" then a long mixed character key,

What confuses me is the fact that I did not change anything on the QA environment

Comment: Is this using VSTS release management? If so, are you getting the error in the log of a task? Can you copy-paste a screenshot?

Comment: I have added the screenshot as per the request @VijayMachiraju

Comment: "Replace Tokens" task cannot find any file with ".exe.config" extension in the path you specified, can you check if the file exist in that folder?

Comment: Thanks a lot Eddie, I accidential edited path to where the files are sitting hence it could not pick them up anyore, thanks much appreciated @Eddie-MSFT